# How does Google App Engine remote_api work

Tags: google-app-engine

As I understand it, and I may be wrong, but GAE's remote_api allows one application to access another application's datastore. I'll be blunt I don't understand how this works. I have read the [article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) that everyone likes to point to, but I still don't understand how you can link two applications. Can someone explain it to me, perhaps with a small example or just point me to a tutorial that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Think of remote_api as a remote shell to your own application. You're not linking two different applications together — there is no way to do that AFAIK — you're just communicating with a single application using a local shell. Your commands are sent over HTTP to a little handler running on your application, which then executes those commands in your app and returns the results. You need to enable remote_api in your `app.yaml` to get that handler running.

Comment: For future reference, it's better to post App Engine questions on Stack Overflow. In fact, Stack Overflow is now the official support channel for GAE.